# Are recursive AJAX calls a bad idea?

Tags: jquery, ajax, recursion, promise

I have a simple function to pull in an array of templates:

```
function getTemplates(names, done, templates, index) {
    if (!index) index = 0;
    if (!templates) templates = {};
    if (index === names.length) return done(templates);
    $.ajax({
        url: '/templates/' + names[index] + '.min.html',
        success: function (data, status, xhr) {
            templates[names[index++]] = data;
                return getTemplates(names, done, templates, index);
        }
    });
}
```

It seems logical to me to just go from one to the next until they are all retrieved, then callback to the calling function.  But I'm curious if doing so has any bad side effects.  I haven't seen any so far, but I don't want to go to production with this without first getting some insight on any potential problems.

---

**UPDATE:**
With the help of Google and BenjaminGruenbaum I've devised a solution:

```
function getTemplatesAsync(names, done) {
    var calls = [];
    var templates = {};
    names.forEach(function (name, index) {
        calls.push(
            $.ajax({
                url: '/templates/' + names[index] + '.min.html',
                success: function (data, status, xhr) {
                    templates[names[index++]] = data;
                }
            })
        );
    });
    $.when.apply($, calls).done(function () {
        // using "templates" here feels fragile for some reason.  Am I wrong?
        return done(templates);
    });
}
```

I'm using `templates` here because I need to be able to refer to each template by name, but somehow it feels fragile or unreliable.  Does this look like a safe thing to do?

Comment: You'd have better to get all your datas in one ajax request instead

Comment: Although it looks recursive (and I also use the term recursive Ajax for this) technically your function exits before it is called again, so is not actually recursive... perhaps we should call them "chained"? Ajax :)

Comment: The simple generalised answer is NO, it's not safe! Reason being, web servers can and do, by variety of means, limit the number of simultaneous connections. Therefore the scenario you paint in the question may test out fine but then fail to scale up when you go live. If the server is under your control AND you understand it AND you are confident it will scale up, then by all means allow torrents of simultaneous requests. However, my general advice is to have your client-side scripts make sequential requests. The performance loss will be trivial compared with total shutout by the server!

Comment: @Roamer-1888, so it seems that Benjamin's answer does what I was hoping to do, but my initial code is the safest approach.  It does all the requests sequentially, which is less strain on the server.

Comment: @Stephen, yes that's my opinion but with the proviso, as I already indicated, that if you can devise a test strategy to give you the confidence that the server can take the stress, then by all means allow request torrents.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your updated code is much better than your initial one, but it still has a few issues, the main one being mixing promises and callbacks instead of using language facilities (Return value) and not using mappings.

### Some improvements can be:

- returning the promise instead of a callback argument
- using `.map` instead of forEach with push.
- Using `.then` instead of a success callback for avoiding two handlers for the same thing and potentially unspecified behavior (does the when execute first? Does the `success:`?)

### We can do something like:

```
function getTemplatesAsync(names) {
    return $.when.apply(null,names.map(function (name, index) {
        return $.get('/templates/' + names[index] + '.min.html');
    }).then(function(results){
         // map arguments to names
         return Array.prototype.reduce.call(arguments, function(obj,cur,idx){
               obj[names[idx]] = cur;
               return obj;
         },{});
    });
}
```

**Which lets you do:**

```
getTemplatesAsync(names).then(function(templates){
     // access templates here
});
```

Comment: To be fair, the correct solution would probably be to minify the templates together and make one AJAX request.

Comment: It doesn't seem to do as intended.  `obj[names[idx]] = cur;` seems to do as intended, but `templates` in the `then` callback is undefined.

Comment: @StephenCollins missin return obj for the reducer, when you return undefined it sets it as undefined for the next call, will fix shortly.

Comment: Fixed :) Make sure you understand why it fixes the problem.

Comment: You need a second `)` before `.then()`, and it needs to be `cur[0]` for my purposes.  I'm looking into `reduce`; i've never used it before.  Also, minifying/concatenating the templates makes sense to me in principle, but how would I distinguish them if they are all in one file?

Comment: Look into how Angular manages it's template cache. A simple strategy would be to store them in a JSON object whose keys are file names and values are template contents

Comment: Well that's essentially what I'm doing here.  Unfortunately since I'm using doT.js I don't have the option of doing that and still having doT understand it.  Though I could just modify doT and add it...

Answer (score 5):

Yes. Making multiple AJAX calls this way is a bad idea, but possibly not for the reason that you think.

This is going to cause all of your calls to be executed sequentially rather than making the calls in parallel and waiting for them to finish that way.

You'd be far better off using [promises](https://api.jquery.com/promise/) to make all of your calls and then waiting for all of them to finish before continuing. It would look something like:

```
var promises = [], templates = [], i;
for(i = 0; i < names.length; i++) {
    promises.push($.get('/templates/' + names[i] + '.min.html'));
}

$.when.apply($, promises).done(function(responses) {
   for(i = 0; i < responses.length; i++) {
       templates.push(responses[i][0]);
   }
});
```

Comment: An exception is when you need to throttle your traffic. Mobile browsers will not handle large quantities of requests at the same time.

Comment: Promises, promises... ;)

Comment: This approach isn't working for me.  The `$.when.apply(...).done()` is  being executed, but the value of `responses` is a single Promise, not a set of results.

Comment: @StephenCollins it is an array, each element in the array (responses[0], responses[1],...) is the result of a single call.

Comment: You should consider using `.map` here instead of creating an array and pushing to it.

Comment: @BenjaminGruenbaum, looks like the `done()` function signature changes.  If `promises` is an array of 2 Promises, then it has 2 arguments, if `promises` contains 3 items, `done` has 3 arguments, etc.  This makes it useless for my purposes because I may add new templates later.  I need something that has one argument, an array, so I can just have my callback pass that array back.

Comment: @StephenCollins for what it's worth you're way better off using a real promise library like Bluebird: `Promise.map(names,function(name){ return $.get("/templates/" + name + ".min.html"); }).then(function(responses){ /* access responses array here */ });` is the complete code for the above.

Comment: @StephenCollins I'm posting a better solution :P

Answer (score 3):

Although it looks recursive (and I also use the term *recursive Ajax* for this) technically your function exits before it is called again, so is not actually recursive... perhaps we should call them "chained" Ajax calls as it is just chaining Async events together? :)

There is no problem doing it this way, if you do not mind queuing your Ajax request one at a time. I used it this way a few times to ensure bandwidth use was acceptable.

You need to be careful of edge cases, so that it handles server errors gracefully.

*This is actually a good technique for handling mobile devices which will choke on a large number of requests going out at once.*

I wrote have a plugin that loaded sections of a massive application form via Ajax and found devices like the iPad could not cope with more than a handful of simultaneous Ajax requests. I wound up using recursive/chained Ajax calls to solve the problem (and had the bonus of not choking our server too) :)

Comment: Sure it is recursive, recursive doesn't mean you have to stack a function on top of itself in the stack - it means that the logic repeats in a self similar way : i.e. "A call to getTemplates means doing x, y and then calling getTemplates".

Comment: @Benjamin Gruenbaum: Recursive in programming is normally defined as as *the function being defined is applied within its own definition* which is vague enough to cover this situation. Your `x,y then calling getTemplate` example does not match this case as here it simply registers itself in an anonymous callback function for later processing then control is relinquished. The calls are chained and not recursive in the typical sense of recursion but I realise this is just splitting hairs. The definition of recursion in `the white book` when I start coding was "see recursion" :)