# Making multiple AJAX calls recursively is a bad idea

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, recursion, promise

I already gone through this question. 
[Are recursive AJAX calls a bad idea?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22940055/are-recursive-ajax-calls-a-bad-idea)
Here answer provided by Justin Niessner is good (by using promises) But my problem is little bit different.
I want to call `10 ajax calls` recursively. Like when first ajax call completed , I render that data(provided by ajax call) in my view and at the same time I will call second ajax call.So my code sample will look like this:

```
(function() {
    var downloadAsync = function(url, callback) {
        var httpRequest;
        if (window.XMLHttpRequest) {
            httpRequest = new XMLHttpRequest();
        } else if (window.ActiveXObject) {
            httpRequest = new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
        }
        httpRequest.onreadystatechange = function() {
            if (httpRequest.readyState === 4 && httpRequest.status === 200) {
                callback(httpRequest.responseText);
            }
        }
        httpRequest.open("GET", url, true);
        httpRequest.send();
    }

    function renderData(data) {
        //data render logic          
    }
    downloadAsync("mathmatics.json", function(response) {
        renderData(response);
        downloadAsync("science.json", function(response) {
            renderData(response)
            downloadAsync("english.json", function(response) {
                renderData(response);
                ....................................
            });
        });
    });

})();
```

I want to render each data as soon as possible. So in success of every ajax call I am rendering that data.
Here are my problems :

Is there is any better of doing this ?  can I use `promises` in this case ? (**rendering data
    is necessary as soon as possible**). If yes than how and if no than what is the best way of doing this kind of calls.

1. Note : rendering data on ajax success is my priority.
2. Edit - Browser support -latest chrome,firefox and IE-11.
3. Edit - according to comments improvement :

> ```
> var array = ["mathematics.json", "science.json", "english.json"];
> for (var i = 0; i < array.length; i++) {
>   downloadAsync(array[i], renderData);
> }
>
> function renderData(data) {
>   console.log(data);
>     }
> ```

Comment: since you aren't sending any data , what is reason for needing the nested calls in the first place? If it is just to keep them in order, can send them sooner and use promises to keep order

Comment: If you just keep order in what data goes where, you can just call all the ajax functions in a simple loop, and the browser will queue them, but they will of course not finish in order, you'll have to keep that order yourself, but that's easy, even without promises, just pass an index to the `renderData` function to know what request finished etc.

Comment: @charlietfl sorry my mistake , edited the question.

Comment: still doesn't explain why you can't simply create an array of url's and loop over array.

Comment: @charlietfl I included code as you said. I am curious about to know that In such kind of situation this is the best solution ? or I can improve it ?

Comment: PLEASE specify what browsers you'd like to support.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Nested Ajax calls work.  There are some drawbacks though:

- If you're doing real error handling, it can get quite messy with multiple nested ajax calls and you often end up repeating error handling at every level of the nesting.
- In some people's opinion, deep nesting can lead to less readable code than other techniques
- If any code in the nesting can throw exceptions, you need a lot of exception handlers to properly catch all the exceptions and it's difficult to propagate the errors cleanly - because these are async callbacks, you can't just catch the exceptions in one place.

**See Edits at End of Answer Now that the Intent of the Question has been Clarified**

As for other ways to do this, there are some advantages to using promises.  Since none of your calls depends upon the previous set of calls and you just want to insert the results in proper order, you can significantly speed up your end-to-end time by sending all the ajax requests at once and then just serialize the results back in order.  That can be done with manual coding or it can be done fairly easily with promises.

You don't say what promise library you plan to use (there are several), but here's one done using Bluebird (though the code would be similar or identical with other libraries):

```
(function() {
    // downloadAsync now returns a promise rather than uses a callback
    function downloadAsync(url) {
        return new Promise(function(resolve, reject) {
            var httpRequest = new XMLHttpRequest();
            httpRequest.onreadystatechange = function() {
                if (httpRequest.readyState === 4) {
                    if (httpRequest.status === 200) {
                        resolve(httpRequest.responseText);
                    } else {
                        reject(httpRequest.status);
                    }
                }
            }
            httpRequest.open("GET", url, true);
            httpRequest.send();
        }
    }

    function renderData(data) {
        //data render logic          
    }
    var items = ["mathmatics.json", "science.json", "english.json"];
    var promises = items.map(function(path) {
        return downloadAsync(path);
    });

    // Promise.all collects all the promise results and 
    // calls .then only when all the promises have completed
    Promise.all(promises).then(function(data) {
        data.forEach(renderData)
    }).catch(function(e) {
        // handle errors here
    });

})();
```

This has the performance advantage of it requests all the data at once, but then processes the results in the original request order.  This shortens the end-to-end time compared to serializing like you had with request-response-request-response-request-response.  This starts with request-request-request and Promise.all does the work for us to put the results into the right order for us to process them in the order that we requested them.

---

If you want to display any column as soon as possible, you don't even have to wait for all to complete and the second part of the code can be this:

```
// note we are passing an index here so you know which column it is in case that isn't
// already specified in the data
function renderData(index, data) {
    //data render logic          
}

// are you sure you want a leading / on only one of these three?
var items = ["mathmatics.json", "science.json", "english.json"];
items.forEach(function(value, index) {
    downloadAsync(value).then(function(data) {
        renderData(index, data);
    });
});
```

Promises aren't benefiting you as much here as you could code a similar structure with your callback mechanism.

---

Without promises, you could just use your original `downloadAsync()` function and do this:

```
downloadAsync("mathmatics.json", renderData);
downloadAsync("science.json", renderData);
downloadAsync("english.json", renderData);
```

This will launch all three in parallel and render each one immediately as the data arrives.

---

Or, if you had more than three and you put the filenames in an array of any length and you can do this:

```
["mathmatics.json", "science.json", "english.json"].forEach(function(item) {
   downloadAsync(item, renderData);
});
```

Comment: @pandit - Note: depending upon what browser versions you are targeting, you may need to use a Promise library such as Bluebird or Q to guarantee promise support.

Comment: ,I have 10 columns and I am showing data of each ajax call in a columns , my idea is to show the data as soon as possible .thats why I am doing that way. In your approach I can render whole data only when all ajax call completed.

Comment: @pandit - I code it that way because that's how your original code worked (it did one at a time) and I assumed you wanted it that way.  It does not have to be that way if the requirements or desire is different.  I can add an example like that to my answer.

Comment: Exactly, My concern was that only "Promises aren't benefiting you as much here as you could code this same structure with your callback mechanism." can you please provide any good link for promises real time use cases. Thanks a lot.

Comment: I have never seen code that does `if(window.XMLHttpRequest)` alongside promises and Array#forEach until this day :D

Comment: @BenjaminGruenbaum - yeah, presumably that could be removed (I just copied the OP's existing code there).  I will clean it up.

Comment: Also, this makes both requests in parallel - is that what OP wanted?

Comment: @BenjaminGruenbaum - yes, it appears the OP wants to make all requests in parallel and, in fact, render each result as they come back (per the OP's latest comments).  That was certainly not clear in the original question though.

Comment: @pandit - now that your desires are a little clearer, I added several more options to the end of my answer.

Answer (score 0):

Since you're doing new browsers - your life can be a *lot* simpler with promises.

You're checking for things not relevant since IE6, you can simplify your work a great deal.

Here is how:

```
function downloadAsync(url){
    return new Promise(function(fulfill, reject){
        var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest;
        xhr.open("GET", url);
        xhr.onload = function(){ resolve(xhr.responseText); });
        xhr.onerror = reject;
        xhr.send();
    });
}
```

No need for the checks for XMLHttpRequest, no needs for the status checks, a simple onload - note we've also added an onerror so we don't silence errors.

Now, let's download all three at once:

```
// your pages
var pages = ["mathmatics.json", "science.json", "english.json"]
// your downloads and renders 
var promises = pages.map(downloadAsync).
                    /*map(JSON.parse).*/
                     map(renderData);
Promise.all(promises).then(function(){
    // code here runs when it's all done.
});
```